# Redirect Safari versions older than 6

Tags: jquery, redirect, safari

I am trying to redirect Safari users with an older version than 6. 
My code, works, but it also redirects Safari user with a newer version of Safari. Any ideas of what is wrong? For example users with 6.2 and 7.1 are redirected (only versions I have tested.)

My code:

```
        $(window).load(function() {     
        var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var safari = uagent.match(/safari\/(\S+)/);
        var chrome = uagent.match(/chrome\/(\S+)/);
        var MIN_SAFARI_VERSION = 600;
        if(safari && !chrome) {
            if (parseFloat(safari[1]) < MIN_SAFARI_VERSION) {
                window.location.href = "http://google.com"
            }
         }
    });
```

Update: Found another, working, solution:

```
$(window).load(function() {             
        var bVer;

        if( navigator.appVersion && /\bsafari\/\d+/i.test( navigator.appVersion ) 
            && 
            ( bVer = navigator.appVersion.match( /\bversion\/(\d+)/i )) && Number( bVer[1] ) <= 5  )
        {
         location.href = 'http://google.com';  
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the value of `safari[1]` on those systems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect Old Browers Safari Users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551837/redirect-old-browers-safari-users)